# Rails mysql Type Error after switching to Ruby 1.9.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not quite sure how to go about diagnosing this issue, after switching my app to Ruby 1.9.1 I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError
wrong argument type Mysql (expected Struct)
```

And it seems the app fails to boot, so I'm not really sure of how to even begin solving this issue. I've made sure all my gems are up to date and they are.

I'm using RVM, ruby 1.9.1, and Rails 3 (beta3), I don't have this problem when running ruby 1.8.7.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ruby 1.9.2-head.

I've never been able to get any of the Rails 3 betas to work on 1.9.1.

Comment: I'm running in to this same issue when using Rails 3.0.7 and Ruby 1.9.2-head (exists in 1.9.2-p180, as well).

Answer (score 0):

A backtrace can help you to track a place of wrong type assignment.
You can try to get some with running any rake task with '-t' option.

```
rake test -t
rake db:migrate -t
```

or maybe just running "script/console" will show you some.

PS: you can list available rake tasks with "rake -T" command

Answer (score 0):

After installing ruby 1.9.2-head on my RVM (which btw crashed with FactoryGirl), I came pack to my 1.9.2-p180 and realized it was probably just a matter of rebooting the server :)